# Propagating events between JQuery.Deferred objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

How can I propagate all events on one JQuery.Deferred() object to another ?

Is there a better / simpler / shorter way then handling both `.fail` and <strike>`.then`</strike> `.done` by calling the other objects `.rejectWith` and `.resolveWith` ?
I am assuming that I don't have to handle <strike>`.done`</strike> `.then` as it will be called when I call Reject or resolve.

I suspect that maybe this can be done using `.pipe` but I am not sure how.

UPDATE:

Note: I also I fixed some of the text above per @Frédéric Hamidi's comment.

What I am trying to achieve was the following:

I had a API that was making ajax calls to the server, 
they would return the ajax object (which is a $.Deferred itself).

At some point I needed to handle a situation where I had not net work available (This is for a phonegap application running on a mobile device).

What I wanted to do was that in case of no network connectivity I would display a dialog prompting the user to fix the network issue and hit "retry".

But in this scenario I would not call the $.ajax until the user hits retry so I did not have a $.Defferred object to return the the function that called on the API to begin with.

so I ended up understanding that I could just create a new $.Defferred and return it and on the callback for the retry button call the $.ajax itself setting it to "relay"/propagate the defferred events to the one I just returned by holing it as part of a closure.

But I was not sure of the way to do it. My mixup with the the `.pipe` method is because its description says its a:

> Utility method to filter and/or **chain Deferreds**.

I hoep this makes my Question more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. `then()` covers `fail()` with its second argument, so you don't have to use both at the same time. `pipe()` is indeed the way to pass the result of a deferred call to another one, but even in that case you still have to call `resolveWith()`, `rejectWith()`, and possibly `notifyWith()` (or have something else like `$.ajax()` do that) in order to resolve the piped deferred call. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I read this question and, suddenly, I realised that I have *no idea* about the whole concept of `jQuery.deferred`. ...there goes another night's sleep. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want a Deferred to resolve/reject and notify with the exact same value as your ajax request? If so, assuming your Deferred object is called defer, the following code will do the trick:

```
$.ajax( ... ).done( defer.resolve ).fail( defer.reject ).progress( defer.notify );
```

It works because defer.resolve, defer.reject and defer.notify are lexically bound: the context (this) and values (arguments) are passed properly so you just effectively forwarded the state of the ajax promise into the new deferred.

Comment: just to clarify - when you say lexically bound you mean that a call to them would execute with `defer` as the context ? (i.e. `this` within them will be `defer` and thus I do not need to use an additional proxy pattern). how do you know that this is the case?

Comment: I wrote the code, that's how I know ;) `this` won't be `defer`, it will be whatever context is given by ajax. However, since resolve, reject and notify are all defined within a closure, they will use the internal structures of `defer` properly and as expected.

Comment: :) I am honored. Is this documented anywhere? I did something similar but since I did not know that they where closures I proxied them (again) using `$.proxy(deffered,'reject')`.
also maybe there should be a shortcut for this - maybe `.tee(defer)`.

Comment: There are blog posts talking about it but the main documentation would benefit for some more infos for sure. Proxying reject like you do will effectively lock the rejection context, see http://jsfiddle.net/5Q9WH/ for some clarifications

Comment: Thanks for an excelent example. Would it be correct to say that the (onDone) handler is called within the same context that .resolve was called with? (and normal scenarios would usually pass the deferred objects as .resolve or .reject would usually be called directly on it.)

Comment: jQuery Deferred `resolve`, `reject`, `notify` and `state` are always bound to the original deferred instance. You may test it in the browser console: `var d1 = jQuery.Deferred(), d2 = d1; d1.resolve(); d2.state(); // => "resolved"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 deferred objects, d1 and d2, you can propagate from d2 to d1 with: `d2.then(d1.resolve,d1.reject,d1.notify)`

An example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bgrossi/XTJEf/