# Pattern for wrapping a jQuery Deferred around another Deferred?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

What I need, basically, is to expose a Deferred before it's actually created.  For example, say I have some object that is wraps an Ajax query, but before it starts it needs to expose a Deferred that represents the resolution of that query:

```
var object = new AjaxRunningThing();
// Get a Deferred wrapping the Ajax operation
var ajaxResult = object.getAjaxResult();

// Later...

// Now the object is going to initiate the Ajax request
object.startAjax();
```

Right now I just link them up manually so that the resolution of the "real" Deferred is chained into the "facade" one:

```
// in getAjaxResult()
var publicDeferred = $.Deferred();

// in startAjax()
var privateDeferred = $.ajax(...);
privateDeferred.then(
    function() { publicDeferred.resolve.apply(this, arguments); },
    function() { publicDeferred.reject.apply(this, arguments); }
);
```

I can't help but think there's a better way to do this, though.

-- Edit ---

Thinking about it more, what I'm looking for is really a proxy -- searching for "proxy" led me to this post, which describes what I'm looking for and includes a better (although still not totally transparent) solution: [Propagating events between JQuery.Deferred objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267286/propagating-events-between-jquery-deferred-objects)

Comment: I don't get it, if the ajax call returns a deferred object, why would you need to wrap that in another Deferred that gets resolved at the same time with the same arguments?

Comment: Because before that ajax call occurs, some other component is going to ask for it -- the Deferred here is "some Ajax call that will occur in the indefinite future"

Comment: Your solution is fine - there are more clever solutions in Q promises but jQuery promises are _really_ bare bones and basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving promises in cascade is pretty trivial. We see it all the time, very often when a single promise would suffice. What you need here could be termed a "Deferred legal-pattern" (as opposed to the "Deferred anti-pattern").

For me, this is more about how the code is factored than simply coding a cascade.

Here's one possible approach :

```
function getLatentAjaxPromise(options) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred(),
        promise = dfrd.promise(),
        jqXHR;

    // monkeypatch the promise with a `go()` method.
    promise.go = function(opts) {
        if(!jqXHR) { // in case .go() is called more than once.
            jqXHR = $.ajax($.extend(options, opts)).then(dfrd.resolve, dfrd.reject);
        }
        return promise;
    };
    return promise;
};
```

This would allow :

- the Deferred object itself to be kept private,
- ajax options to be passed to `getLatentAjaxPromise` and/or `.go`,
- promise chains to be built onto `getLatentAjaxPromise()` and/or `.go()`.

Call as follows :

```
var latentAjaxPromise = getLatentAjaxPromise(...).then(...);

//and later ...
latentAjaxPromise.go(...).then(...);
```

There shouldn't be any adverse consequences of twin promise chains, though you would maybe need to keep your wits about you. From the consumer perspective, it's not immediately obvious that both chains stem from the same promise.

I will be interested to see if anyone can spot any obvious flaws in the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Just for closure, here is the solution that I wound up with.  It uses pieces from the other answers here, but this is the functionality that I needed:

```
// Private deferred that will be resolved when the Ajax is complete
var _done = $.Deferred();
// Expose the deferred as a promise, so it's read-only to other components
var done = _done.promise();

// ... other components add their own callbacks to `done`

// Later, run the ajax, and resolve the deferred based on that
$.ajax(...).then(
    _done.resolve, _done.reject, _done.notify);
```